# Can I use windbg as a post mortem debugger for Windows services?

Tags: windows, windows-services, windbg, postmortem-debugging

I have Windbg set as the default post mortem debugger.  I did this by running `windbg -I`.  However, this only appears to catch unhandled exceptions from applications run by the user I'm logged on as, not Windows services.  Does anyone know how I can configure windbg to catch these too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you plan to debug the service application from the beginning of its execution, including its initialization code, this preparatory step is required.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553427(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

When WinDbg is running as postmortem debugger it is launched by the process that is crashing.  In case of a service it is launched by a process running in session 0 and has no access to the desktop.

You can configure AeDebug registry to launch a process that creates a crash dump and debug the crash dump.  You can use ntsd -server and connect to the server.

Comment: and one good tool to use to create a dump is procdump, by sysinternals.com

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use WinDbg to attach or launch any service even those not run by the user: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824344

Comment: Thanks Ed, yes, this is what I'm doing at the moment.  However, it'd be nice to be able to use automatic uncaught exception handling in the same way as you can for non-service processes.  (i.e. without the need to attach all the time)